# Prism WPF Navigation in Plug-in app

Tags: wpf, plugins, navigation, prism, prism-6

I am developing a plug-in for a commercial software. It has to be a class library. From this class library, I would like to show a window that supports navigation. First here it is my bootstrapper (using Ninject).

```
class BootStrapper : NinjectBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Kernel.Get<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Kernel.RegisterTypeForNavigation<AViewModel>();
            Kernel.RegisterTypeForNavigation<BViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

To show the window, I am using `ShowDialog()`. The windows appears with AViewModel as expected but Navigation (through `RequestNavigation`) won't work. **Although through debugging I found that the BViewModel receives `OnNavigatedTo` call. However, the interface never updates to the second view**.

My first impression is using ShowDialog() blocks navigation somehow, but I noticed even changing it `Show()` won't solve the problem.

Is there a way to solve this issue? I am open to any suggestion/ other frameworks.

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't `ShowDialog` block? I guess, `Show` would be better here.

Comment: @Haukinger, even `Show()` won't work!